# What am I doing wrong here (Timed Shutdown script)

Tags: windows, batch-file, shutdown, windows-10

I've made a simple program like this in C# before as an exercise.
I'm doing it now as a .bat script.
So... What am i doing wrong?:

```
@echo off
title TimedShutdown
color 02
mode con:cols=50 lines=5
:start
cls
set "quit=a"
set /p Minutes= Minutes to shutdown? ('a'= cancel shutdown) -

if %Minutes%==%quit% (shutdown /a
pause goto start)

set "Seconds=%Minutes%*60"
shutdown /s /t %Seconds%
pause
goto Loop

:Loop
cls
set /a Seconds=%Seconds%-1
set /a Minutes=%Seconds%/60
set /a Remainder=%Seconds% %% 60
echo %Minutes%m %Remainder%s remaining...
timeout 1 >nul
goto Loop
```

As you can see this isn't a very complicated script so I'm sure you people don't need an explanation on what it does.
It seems to work just fine, except that the shutdown command part itself doesn't seem to work. I threw in a pause command after it to see what went wrong and I see [this.](http://puu.sh/jnxoc/86574eec2d.png) What on earth does that mean!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `&` between commands on one line: `pause & goto start)`
2. Add the missing `/a`: `set /a Seconds=%Minutes% * 60`
3. To debug batch files comment out `@echo off`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even know about using "&" for same line commands. I've almost always put all commands in their own lines in batches. Should have noticed the missing "/a" too... I'll go ahead and blame my lack of sleep. Anyways, works now. :)